# Periodic work manger is not working when app is closed

Tags: android

I have created a periodic work manager. I have a list of url in Room database. when work manager is started it gets the urls and check if it is working or not and save the result in database. But when app is closed the workmanager is not working periodically. Here is a complete code. I have started the workmanager in Application class.

```
class UrlCheckWorker(context: Context, params: WorkerParameters) : Worker(context, params) {

companion object {
    val TAG = "UrlCheckWorker"

    fun scheduleRadioStatusChecker(context: Context) {
        val constraints = Constraints.Builder()
            //   .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
            .build()

        val periodicWorkRequest = PeriodicWorkRequestBuilder<UrlCheckWorker>(
            repeatInterval = 20, // Repeat interval in minutes
            repeatIntervalTimeUnit = TimeUnit.MINUTES
        )
            .setConstraints(constraints)
            .build()

        WorkManager.getInstance(context).enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(
            TAG,
            ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP,
            periodicWorkRequest
        )
    }

    fun isUrlValid(url: String): Boolean {
        val request: Request = Request.Builder().url(url).build()
        try {
            OkHttpClient().newCall(request).execute().use { response ->
                return response.isSuccessful
            }
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            return false
        }
    }
}

override fun doWork(): Result {
    
    AppDatabase.init(applicationContext)

    val list = AppDatabase.getInstance().urlDao().all


    for (station in list) {
        val isValid = isUrlValid(station.url)
        val timeStatus = TimeStatus(0, station.id, System.currentTimeMillis(), isValid)
        AppDatabase.getInstance().urlDao().insertTimeStatus(timeStatus)
    }

    return Result.success()
}
```

}